# Apply customization when the new project is loaded

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to apply customization settings to QGIS consistently at two moments:

1. When QGIS opens;
2. When new project (with some layers) is loaded.

My code:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def customize():
    #some
    #customization
    #code

iface.initializationCompleted.connect(customize)
QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(customize)
```

At first moment code works well. But `legendLayersAdded` signal works only after I'm adding any other layer to an already loaded project.

Is there a signal emitted after any project (new one or existing with some layers) was loaded into QGIS?

Comment: You made me look into the documentation. Closest I can find is readProject emitted when project is being read [signal]. Sounds about what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked a bit more into the documentation, and apart for QgsProject, there are also QgisInterface signals:

> **newProjectCreated** Emitted when starting an entirely new project note
> This is similar to projectRead(); plug-ins might want to be notified
> that they’re in a new project.

> **projectRead**   Emitted when a project file
> is successfully read note This is useful for plug-ins that store
> properties with project files.

Complete description e.g.: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/other/QgisInterface.html

Comment: Thank you, @Miro! That's it! projectRead is what I need for this case. https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/other/QgisInterface.html#qgis.gui.QgisInterface.projectRead