# Setting coordinate display axis order for new projects with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

Using QGIS 3.28.1 (Windows), I wanted to automatically change the default coordinate display axis order of a new QGIS project to "XY". Unfortunately there is no global setting for this, so I created a `startup.py` file with the following code:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject,QgsMessageLog,Qgis

QgsProject.instance().displaySettings().setCoordinateAxisOrder(Qgis.CoordinateOrder.XY)
QgsMessageLog.logMessage('CoordinateAxisOrder: %s' % QgsProject.instance().displaySettings().coordinateAxisOrder(),'Custom',Qgis.Info)
```

Although the message log shows me that the axis order has been changed, QGIS shows no change at all.

Do I need to use any signal to change the default coordinate display axis order?
And if possible, can I change the value via Python plugin?

Comment: What do you mean by x and y?

Comment: That's the API equivalent of the coordinate order "Easting, Northing (Longitude, Latitude)"

Comment: Your code is only applying the setting to the blank empty default project that QGIS creates upon launch. You will need to find either a global QGIS profile setting for this or use a signal that is not project instance specific https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411712/apply-customization-when-the-new-project-is-loaded?rq=1

Comment: @bugmenot123 thanks a lot! This helped to solve the problem 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @bugmenot123 and [north-road](https://north-road.com/2018/03/09/implementing-an-in-house-new-project-wizard-for-qgis/) (Nyall?) I found a solution using the `newProjectCreated` signal of QGIS iface:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject,QgsMessageLog,Qgis
from qgis.utils import iface

iface.newProjectCreated.connect(lambda: QgsProject.instance().displaySettings().setCoordinateAxisOrder(Qgis.CoordinateOrder.XY))
```